# Is there a way to debug the function file in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm building an Outlook add-in that utilizes the `ItemSend` event. The function I've written for it works well in Outlook 365 web, but not in Outlook for Mac (Insider Fast Preview). The function definitely runs because I can control whether to allow the event and that works, but I'd like to be able to debug it at a more granular level.

I've already followed the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac) for setting up debugging on mac, which allows me to open the safari dev tools for the Taskpane, but there doesn't appear to be any equivalent for the function file. I also tried setting up [vorlon](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs), but it also doesn't appear to attach to the function file.

Is there any way I could attach a debugger or even just view console logs for the function file?

Comment: I'm having similar problems, really need to be able to attach a debugger in order to debug network requests.